# Change certain weirdly formatted df rows into columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with thousands of rows, this sample df gives the different kinds of rows that exist:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['1', '2', '2', '3'],
                  'col2': ['10', '15', '20', '30'],
                    'col3': ['cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat'],
                   'col4': [0.2, 0.9, 'dog', 0.5],
                  'col5': [None, None, 0.3, 'dog'],
                  'col6': [None, None, None, 0.1]})
```

`col1`, `col2` are fine as-is. For the rest of the row, I want `cat`, `dog`, and `catdog` to become column headers. When a column header is present in a row, any value directly after it should be a value in that column.

The rules for each row:

- If a row contains only `cat`, the decimal value goes in the `cat` column ( `dog` and `catdog` columns
  have `None`) .
- If a row contains only `dog`, the decimal value goes in the `dog` column (`cat` and `catdog`
  columns have `None`).
- If a row has both `cat` and `dog`, but only 1 decimal number, that decimal should go under `catdog` as well as `cat` and `dog`.
- If a row has both `cat` and `dog`, but 2 decimal numbers, the decimal number goes under the column that precedes the number (with `None` under `catdog`).

For example, in the first row, `0.2` is directly after `cat`, so it will go in that column (in a row with `1` and `10` from `col1/col2`).

In the third row, `0.3`, is after "`cat`,`dog`", so `0.3` goes in all columns: `cat`, `dog`, and `catdog`.

Desired output:

```
dfoutput = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['1', '2', '2', '3'],
                  'col2': ['10', '15', '20', '30'],
                   'cat': [0.2, None, 0.3, 0.5],
                    'dog': [None, 0.9, 0.3, 0.1],
                    'catdog': [None, None, 0.3, None]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.select` and `np.where`:

```
cond1 = (df['col3']=='cat') & (df['col4']!='dog')
cond2 = (df['col3']=='cat') & (df['col4']=='dog')
cond3 = df['col3']=='dog'
cond4 = df['col5']=='dog'
cond5 = df['col4']=='dog'

df['cat'] = np.select([cond1, cond2], [df['col4'], df['col5']], None)
df['dog'] = np.select([cond3,cond4,cond5], [df['col4'], df['col6'], df['col5']], None)
df['catdog'] = np.where(cond2, df['col5'], None)

df.drop(['col3','col4','col5','col6'], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
 col1 col2   cat   dog   catdog                                                                                                   
0    1   10  0.2   None  None                                                                                                   
1    2   15  None  0.9   None                                                                                                   
2    2   20  0.3   0.3   0.3                                                                                                   
3    3   30  0.5   0.1   None
```